# Angular 5 Kendo UI grid with datepicker editor? Default sort?

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui-angular2

We have an angular 5 app we're developing, and I can't seem to get the datepicker to function correctly in a Kendo grid with inline editing..

```
<kendo-grid-column field="fancyDateField" title="Fancy Date Field" editor="date" format="dd-MM-yyyy">
```

While we get the datePicker, it never binds the chosen value to the previous value in the field; do I need to write a handler for this in the cellClickHandler/callCloseHandler, is this a versioning issue or are the kendo components not ready for this functionality?

Also, does anyone know how to specify the default sort on an angular Kendo grid? I've seen a few examples but nothing seems to work.. it was trivial in UI for jQuery!

Adding plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/eVH8lxCS9Kv4szgcyDAG?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

How to set default filter you can check [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/#toc-filter-row). This demo has defined startup filter.

```
public state: State = {
    skip: 0,
    take: 5,

    // Initial filter descriptor!!!!
    filter: {
      logic: 'and',
      filters: [{ field: 'ProductName', operator: 'contains', value: 'Chef' }]
    }
};
```

Date editor works if column data is of type `Date`.

Here is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sCowqal5t2KZTzKrnxPo?p=preview) that demonstrates start-up filter and date editing.